# Proper Maps: Where is continuity used in this Wikipedia proof?

Tags: general-topology

In [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) on Wikipedia, a proof is given of the statement that any map $f$ from $X\to Y$ that is closed, continuous, and has the property that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact in $X$ for $y\in Y$, is a proper map, i.e. $f^{-1}(C)$ is compact in $X$ if $C$ is compact in $Y$.

However, the proof does not appear to use the continuity assumption anywhere. Is there a mistake in my understanding of the proof, or is true that just the assumptions of closedness and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ being compact are sufficient?

Comment: Continuity is part of the definition of a proper map.

Comment: To get this particular result, you don't need continuity.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your quick responses!